# Cassandra InvalidQueryException: Key may not be empty

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-astra

**InvalidQueryException: Key may not be empty**
When using the Java Driver for DataStax Astra Cassandra DB.

I'm 100% sure that my partitionKey or my clusteringColumns are not empty.
Can someone tell me what this error can mean besides that?

The same code worked 1 hour before what does that exception mean?

Comment: Could you add what you have tried?

Comment: Could you please add the code, and an example of what it is being called with.

Comment: I have an answer to my problem it ByteBuffer.remaining() was null I had to flip() the ByteBuffer thanks anyways guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys but I just found it myself.

I wrote a `Long` into an `ByteBuffer` and didn't use `flip()` afterwards.

```
 public static ByteBuffer toBB(Long x) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    }
    bb.putLong(x);
    bb.flip(); //Added this line here and it works
    return bb;
}
```